# Location module incorrect continent and country mapping?

Tags: 6, views, location

I have a view listing the shops by geographical location. The shops content type is using location CCK field and the same is used in view to filter by continent and country as below, with a custom js script I have altered the view filters, continent and country to behave like a hierarchical select. This is working fine

[image]

However the continent and country mapping in location tables seem to be wrong. The country Cyprus and Turkey is expected to be in continent Europe but location module has preferred to have it under Asia. I ran the following query to find their relation in db.

```
SELECT * FROM location_continent_name cn, 
  location_continent_country cc, 
  countries_api_countries cac
   WHERE cc.continent = cn.code
    AND cc.country = lower( iso2 )
   LIMIT 0 , 250
```

When I looked at Wikipedia for [Cyprus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus) and [Turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey), it says the countries in discussion belongs to Eurasian island country. I don't have much idea about this. I would like to have [Cyprus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus) and [Turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey) under Asia. I am afraid to edit the table rows as it might break any references. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.